# How to send an asynchrone email with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I'm using spring boot 1.5. I'm trying to send async mail when user create an alert but it doesnt work and it doesn't display any error even when I'm debugging but in vain, so here's what I obtain. My question is how to test if my implementation of mail is correct or not, because I don't have any controller of it. Please help. Thank you for any suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can send asynchronous emails easily by using `@Async` annotation on your mail sending method. To enable Async support in your spring boot application use `@EnableAsync` like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringTestAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Create a `MailSender` service and annotate mail sender method with `@Async` like this:

```
@Service
public class MailSenderService {

    @Async
    public void sendMail(....) {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Autowire the above service in your service and then call `sendMessage` method, example:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private MailSenderService mailSenderService;

    User exampleMethod() {
        ..
        ..
        mailSenderService.sendMail(...);
    }
}
```

You can check this link for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

**UPDATE:**
If you want to use java mail api . Then you can take reference of below code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MailService {
    @Autowired
    EnvConfiguration envConfiguration;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailService.class);

    @Async
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String htmlText, String fileName) {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", envConfiguration.getSMTPPort());
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", envConfiguration.smtpAuthorized());
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", envConfiguration.isStarTlsEnabled());
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", envConfiguration.isStarTlsRequired());

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Transport transport = null;
        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(envConfiguration.getEmailFrom().replaceAll("\"", "")));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
            transport = session.getTransport();
            transport.connect(envConfiguration.getEmailHost(), envConfiguration.getEmailUserName(),
                    envConfiguration.getEmailPassword());
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            LOGGER.info("Mail send successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to send email trace" + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                transport.close();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot for your help , but I m already using the annotation @Async, and I called the method sendMail in the service like u have mentionned ,but parameters like ( cc , to , directors , environnement ) are always null as it s  shown in the screenshot ,  those I declared them in my file application.yml , and I set them but it doesnt work , maybe the service doesnt recognize the file application.yml

Comment: I have added a example with java mail . you can try if spring mail does not work for you

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion I just added what you have mentionned but this error diplays , https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wqrF5YjCT3p9rl5wH3tVZvoPRDM6oWEA so I added this on my file application.yml ribbon:
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 10
  ServerListRefreshInterval: 2000
  OkToRetryOnAllOperations: false
  ReadTimeout: 120000 but in vain

Comment: This is not an email issue. This is something different. You are using spring cloud ribbon for load balancing you microservices. the error says server not available. check the server that may be down